# Two relations in one model

Tags: cakephp, relationship

[image: database relation]

Hello

I created the database relation above, as you see one person (staff) can be member of many groups. Every group has a groupleader. How do I manage that relation correctly ?

I'd be thankfull for every hint

Here is what I tried before:

**Staff Model:**

```
    /**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Staffgroup' => array(
            'className' => 'Staffgroup',
            'foreignKey' => 'Staffgroup_groupLeader',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasAndBelongsToMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Staffgroup' => array(
            'className' => 'Staffgroup',
            'joinTable' => 'staff_staffgroups',
            'foreignKey' => 'staff_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'staffgroup_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

**Model Staffgroup**

```
/**
 * hasOne associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Staff' => array(
            'className' => 'Staff',
            'foreignKey' => 'groupLeader',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasAndBelongsToMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Staff' => array(
            'className' => 'Staff',
            'joinTable' => 'staff_staffgroups',
            'foreignKey' => 'staffgroup_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'staff_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `hasMany` association missing in your `Staff` model to represent the "group leader" relationship between `Staff` and `StaffGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're you have an unnecesary relation with the belongsTo. With the HABTM should be enough for handling the relation of "a person can be part of many groups"

For more info you can check the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM)